# Scroll spring on Chrome for overflow elements (like Safari)

Tags: css

Chrome has the momentum scroll spring on the document body (when you pull the scroll, it pulls down and springs back). However, it doesn't do this on `overflow-y: scroll` elements. Safari does do this, however.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body, section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header, footer {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<section>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>end</div>
</section>
<footer></footer>
```

Wondering if there is a way to turn this effect on in CSS for Chrome.

Comment: can you provide working code..?

Comment: @ankitapatel added an example

Comment: what you want to do I am not understand exactly..? because scroll is perfectly work in chrome.

Comment: this is currently not supported in Chrome. Google it and you will see.